# Need specifications to operate this stepper motor with RPi or Arduino

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, stepper-motor, specifications

Here is the disassembled stepper motor that I'm working with:

[image]

[image]

I need to identify this stepper motor that was retrieved from scrap for a project. Budget constraints force us to use the scrap motor. I tried to drive this using a L298 H Bridge, but I couldn't find the right bit sequences to get this running smoothly. I also tried to search for a specifications sheet in the internet with the label, unsuccessfully.

I'm using either an RPi or Arduino board to run this.

I just need a pin diagram and the specifications of the motor, if you guys have seen this type before.

Comment: It will probably have two coils and a common https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=5-wire+stepper+motor&tbm=isch . The resistance between common and any other will have a resistance half that between two coil ends. Apply voltage between common and a pin, then between that pin and another pin. If the motor doesn't move, then you probably have both ends of the same coil. The rest can be worked out from there.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to Ohm-out the connections.  You have 5 points that will be connected to a set of coils somehow.  Figure each coil will have the same DC resistance, so by measuring the resistances between various combinations and comparing then, you can find out how many coils are in the path between any two leads.  From that you can probably determine how the coils are arranged.

Usually these motors have three coils connected in one place, so a total of 4 connections.  Maybe yours has 4 coils, or maybe just a chassis ground wire or something.  Given that 8 coils are visible in the picture, I'd guess you have 4 separate windings with one common.  Again, Ohming it out should answer these questions.

Once you find how to energize individual coils, try each separately and observe where the rotor goes.  The movements will be small, but you should be able to figure out the sequence.

Then you need to determine the maximum current it can handle.  The limiting factor is how hot it gets.  Try a few currents.  Run it at each current for a few minutes or until you think it gets too hot.  There is no size reference in your picture, but I'd probably start with 1 A and then go from there after seeing how warm it gets.  With everything closed up, a conservative temperature is if you can just about hold the motor in your hand for 10 seconds or so.  The inside will be hotter, but if the outside is just at the human discomfort level, then it should be fine.

Comment: It looks like the label specifies 0.8A (maximum?).

Comment: @Chris:  Good point, so that would be a good start.  That probably means one coil with 800 mA thru it and the others 0.  The label also says "thermally protected", which might imply a temperature switch on the common wire.  Real size measurements would give us a guess as to how much power it could dissipate.  The DC resistance would then tell you the voltage or current that would cause that much dissipation.  Or conversely, what is the dissipation with 800 mA thru one coil?